# WPF+Unity: UserControl with usage of services?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, user-controls, unity-container, prism

I've an `UserControl`, which basically looks like this:
[image]

You guessed, the goal is to allow the user to choose a file/folder when clicking on `Browse`and then display the file path in the `TextBox`.

I started my first fully MVVM application(Using Prism+Unity), and I have in fact an `IDialogService` which allows me to show a `MessageBox`, but also display some `OpenFileDialog` and `SaveFileDialog`.

I would like to use the implementation provided for this `IDialogService` in order to display to the user my dialog box once the Browse command is executed.

Since the `UserControl` isn't built with Unity, how to request the implementation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, your `UserControl` needs to get hold of the Unity container you're using, one way or another. If you're instantiating the `UserControl` yourself, you can consider adding it as a constructor parameter; if it's instantiated by the framework you could consider a `Container` property or a setter method. Or you could go with the container as a singleton.

Either way, assuming your `UserControl` has a field like so...

```
IUnityContainer container;
```

...and that you've managed to point it to the container you're using, you should be able to resolve your service the normal way:

```
IDialogService service = container.Resolve<IDialogService>();
service.OpenFileDialog(...);
```

Comment: Okay, interessting to know we can get the service directly with the `IUnityContainer`. What do you recommend to get an instance of it? Having something like a singleton somewhere?

Comment: In my own project I'm using a singleton, yes. (Which is a hassle in the world of unit testing, but what can you do.)

Comment: An alternative to a singleton is to create a property on some objects that's inherently a singleton, such as an App object.